# New to SQL. ORDER BY, DESC and LIMIT query

Tags: sql, select

Beginner in SQL and I want to return the top 200 results from a specific column and keep all the rows in order. Is this correct

```
SELECT
 *
 Column name
FROM
 Table name
ORDER BY
 DESC
LIMIT 200
```

As part of the Google Data Analytics Certificate course I'm required to ask a question.  I suspect my question is correct however the SELECT * and column name syntax could be wrong and looking for the communities guidance.

Comment: No, it's not correct. Any beginner-level SQL tutorial will present you with the correct syntax, so you really don't need the community's guidance for this.

Comment: One of the best things you can do if learning SQL is to install a database system locally so that you can *experiment* and try things out (there are multiple free options available). There are multiple syntax errors here which you should be able to diagnose yourself rather than having to post here and wait for other people to do a syntax check for you.

Comment: Hello both, and thanks for your comments. As I said I'm new to SQL and my apologies for this miss placed question.  Would either of you make any recommendations that I could explore please?

Comment: Note thet `LIMIT` is a product specific syntax. ANSI SQL has `FETCH FIRST 200 ROWS ONLY`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to say which columns you want to use in the order by. Also, if write "select *" you don't need to repeat the column name in the select (in any case in your query you have to put a "," between "*" and "column name").

You should want something like this

```
SELECT
 *
FROM
 Table_name
ORDER BY Column_name DESC
LIMIT 200
```

If you want a single column in output run this

```
SELECT
 Column_name
FROM
 Table_name
ORDER BY Column_name DESC
LIMIT 200
```

Comment: Two notes: 1) Tables have columns, not fields, 2) It is not recommended to use `*`, it's far better to write out the column names that should be selected (even if that are all).

Comment: Appreciate your response, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I usually do not use this syntax, just use

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM Table_name 
ORDER BY Column_name ASC/DESC 
LIMIT 200;
```

I think it might be a mis understanding for the reader side that as this query selects the column, why did he need to mention "*" here? and that person will check this query on the DBMS Client app to ensure.

Comment: Thank you for this response, and noted. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax would be this

```
SELECT *
FROM Table name
ORDER BY Column name DESC
LIMIT 200;
```

with this select you get the 200 first records of Table name ordered by Column name

ORDER BY always needs one or more columns by which to order the result

Comment: Much appreciated and tahnk you.  Makes sense to me now